# Why WebStorm emphasizes in red correctly TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, webstorm, createjs

WebStorm emphasizes TypeScript in red. I use createjs. And almost the entire project is highlighted in red. However, before that, for other PC all was OK. What am I doing wrong? What i can do, to fix a error.

For example, in class easeljs.d.ts, where all classes of "easel" were declared. WebStorm write about, I can't override DisplayObject method (clone, set, setTransform e.t.c).

Compiling TS to JS is going well.

[That I see in my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk4Ck.jpg). The entire file highlighted these two method (set, setTransform). WebStrom write: "Incompatible override for member from DisplayObject".

And for example, if I create a class extended of DisplayObject, I can't add his on a screen. Because WebStrom does not consider his a DisplayObject successor.

Comment: So, I presume you want to know what to change to make it not red? If that's true, then you should say so in your question.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have edited a question.

Comment: Can you maybe post a screenshot of this? One possible (but unlikely solution) is that you accidentally did a manual override on the file type detection.

Comment: Thanks for the picture. Never mind my suspicion. What exactly is the error message it tells you (if you hover over it, for example)?

Comment: I just pasted those definition files into the typescript playground – works fine. What version of WebStorm are you using? Are you sure you didn't accidentally change any of the definition files (maybe try redownloading them from DefinitelyTyped)?

Comment: I think this bug may have been addressed in [WEB-10830](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10830), respectively [WEB-10730](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10730). Please check your WebStorm build to be at least 136.1141 or try updating.

Comment: I used WebStorm 7.0.1. I think after update problem may disappeared. Because code from WEB-10830 also causes an error. Many thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a known bug which has been fixed in build 136.1141:

- [WEB-10830](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10830)
- [WEB-10730](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10730)